# How to formulate data object for POST request in AJAX

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, api, stringify

I have the following curl POST request to connect to a node.js API.

```
curl --request POST \
 --url http://localhost:3001/api/v1/login\
 --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 --data '{
    "username": "asdfsdfs",
    "email": "bla",
    "password": "dkasdjf333"
}'
```

However, I struggle with formulating the matching object for passing the POST request in AJAX for it and I get the 500 error from my API server and the browser console says: ''TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined''.
I used 2 types of data object as can be seen below.

```
//Version 1 which failed
 var loginData = {
 username: 'asdfsdfs',
 email: 'bla',
 password: 'dkasdjf333'
};
//version 2 which failed as well
var stringifiedJson = JSON.stringify({
 username: 'asdfsdfs',
 email: 'bla',
 password: 'dkasdjf333'
});


$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/v1/login',
 data: loginData,
 processData: false,
 contentType: false,
 dataType: 'json'
 }).done(function(data) {
 console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: how do you know your console error has anything to do with the piece of code you just pasted?

Comment: Why are you setting processData and contentType to false, should your contentType be application/json?

Comment: are meaning to pass in your `loginData` when you should probably be passing in your `stringifiedJson` ?

Comment: I was trying out two different methods. One the Json object as is and once the JSON object used with JSON.stringify. The console error has had to do with it, as its being unit tested incrementally and it was the only source of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the contentType of your pist request to JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    ...,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
});
```

Comment: Thank you. that brought me to the right solution. I did not had to add the charset however. Its working together with the JSON.stringify object.